# Why Node.js `process.stdout.on('data',...)` hangs?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

Why is this code hangs forever

```js
process.stdout.on('data',function(){});
```

while the `process.stdout` is a WriteStream and even not supposed to have the 'data' event? I'm using node v16.13.0 if matters.